# How do I find out what version of WordPress is running?

Tags: wordpress

I have just taken over someone's hosted WordPress site.  How do I find out what version he is running?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Look in wp-includes/version.php

```
/**
 * The WordPress version string
 *
 * @global string $wp_version
 */
$wp_version = '2.8.4';
```

Answer (score 75):

Unless he edited some code to delete this, you should be able to view source on the site and look for this meta tag:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.7.1" />
```

That will give you the version.

Comment: Excellent tip that allows for quickly checking without looking up credentials for any one of 100 client accounts and log in to the FTP! An even quicker way is to "Click the W logo" as per the below answer - again, if you have credentials at the ready ;)

Comment: Did this change? My WordPress site does not have a meta name="generator" tag in the source.

Comment: The meta tag can be removed by a theme or plugin so that the version of WordPress is hidden, so that it can't be targeted with malicious intent by those seeking out older/unstable verisons. The other methods listed here could still work.

Comment: I'm getting the less than helpful `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com" />` Guess maybe this doesn't work for sites living on wordpress.com?

Answer (score 43):

On the **Admin Panel Dashboard**, you can find a box called "**Right Now**". There you can see the version of the WordPress installation. I have seen this result in WordPress `3.2.1`. You can also see this in version `3.7.1`

[image: WordPress Version 3.7.1]

**UPDATE:**

***In WP Version 3.8.3***

[image: WordPress Version 3.8.3]

In ***WP Version 3.9.1*** Admin Side, You can see the version by clicking the WP logo which is located at the left-top position.

[image: WordPress Version 3.9.1]

You can use `yoursitename/readme.html`

In the WordPress Admin Footer at the Right side, you will see the version info(Version 3.9.1).

[image: In WP 4]

You can get the WordPress version using the following code:

```
<?php bloginfo('version'); ?>
```

The below file is having all version details

```
wp-includes/version.php
```

**Update for WP 4.1.5**

In WP 4.1.5, If it was the latest WP version in the footer right part, it will show the version as it is. If not, it will show the latest WP version with the link to update.

Check the below screenshot.

[image: WP 4.1.5]

Comment: http://yoursitename/readme.html also help you to find the Site's wordpress version

Comment: I think this is THE answer, assuming you have the login/pass.  IMHO. I just deleted readme.html (no offense Matt, LOL)

Comment: This will only be visible as long as no update for WordPress is available.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider What you are trying to say about the answer?

Comment: That this answer is only working as long as no update for the WordPress instance is available. When WordPress detects an available update it replaces all version displays with a "There is an update available" message.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider As per the question, the questionnaire asked which wordpress version a site is having? not to show which is the latest wordpress version.

Answer (score 24):

For any wordpress site, you can go to http://example.com/feed and check the following tag in the xml file to see the version number:

```
<generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.7</generator>
```

Here, 3.7 is the version installed.

Comment: This works even if there is no generator tag in HTML output. May be it is specific to the website I'm interested in, but works for my scenario anyways.

Answer (score 21):

If you came here to find out about how to check WordPress version programmatically, then you can do it with the following code.

```
// Get the WP Version global.
global $wp_version;

// Now use $wp_version which will return a string value.
echo '<pre>' . var_dump( $wp_version ) . '</pre>';
// Output: string '4.6.1' (length=5)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect answer +1, updated: @Ahmad awais it's you. oh this world is too small :-p

Answer (score 20):

Every WP install has a readme.html file.

So just type www.yourdomain.com/readme.html

Comment: False.  Not every install.  I don't remember this in older versions.  Also revealing WordPress version to the world is a security threat.  Everyone should delete readme.html, IMO.

Comment: Comment above by @PJ-Brunet BRINGS UP 2 GOOD POINTS, BUT, for both accuracy & respect, its CLAIMS NEED TO BE TONED DOWN, as should have been done from the start. Notably, via this & my next 3 comments, 3 CORRECTIONS: 1st, beginning ‘False.’ (so suggesting overall false) is misleading indeed to reverse, as the answer approach (by @user1939291) DOES work (often) + outside-useful  + 1st I heard of it (so I give answer +1) so rather the comment should begin say ‘Yes this works (well at least OFTEN) so a method worth adding, BUT it might appear/be a problem and/so cases where it doesn't work.’. ...

Comment: 2nd, if the method actually doesn't always work, tell where ideally exactly; moreover saying merely ‘I don't remember this in older versions.’ is obviously NOT solid proof for saying strong claim ‘Not every install.’ ...though certainly the method won't work if the file has been deleted as the commenter (IMHO mistakenly) suggests users doing, indeed suggest ‘Everyone’ do, so on that most serious point, 3rd, ‘revealing WordPress version to the world is a security threat.’ is too strong a claim including misleading as a way to get good security, ...as 4 corrections, of increasing importance: ...

Comment: ...(a) that's a serious security threat in ONLY {notably limited case: of where (versions very unpredictable (false) +) attacker knows security holes in version + uses ver to significantly-better pick exploit, but I suspect most attacks automated so already try all/many exploits regardless of ver}, moreover (b) using (the short & very predictable) version # as a combo # is hardly a protective combo #(!), moreover (c) such hiding (of this or of the particular CMS in general) {security-thru-obscurity so considered weak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity#Criticism }, ...

Comment: ...moreover (d) {outside world able to determine what CMS a site is running} is, to its owner, almost always at worst a minor if any loss (could be gain) but, to the world, extremely valuable, especially to other developers, to show what works & how things done including what WP can do; SO rather I suggest people DON'T DELETE THIS OR OTHER OFFICIAL FILES (unless official or extreme exceptions); instead for security use {the official methods: esp keeping WP up-to-date & backed-up} which has been enough for all I've seen, but if still not enough, then add WP malware scanner(s) & stopper(s).

Comment: Destiny Architect, your argument doesn't hold water. Read the Wikipedia article you quoted (last line of the opening, "only security mechanism," and the next section after your anchor, which directly refutes your claims). Your, "suspicion," that attacks are over-automated is conjecture and poor practice (attacks between discovery and application of an implemented patch gain higher success rates). @PJBrunet is correct on his first posit and his second is a good recommendation (better than yours).

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way would be to use the `readme.html` file that comes with every WordPress installation *(unless you deleted it)*.

`http://example.com/readme.html`

Note: it looks like the `readme.html` file no longer outputs the current WordPress version. So, there is no way, for now, to see the current WordPress version without logging into the dashboard.

Comment: yeah its cool, because in some cases we see version.php empty

Answer (score 7):

On the Admin panel in the footer you should see the words "Wordpress x.x" where x.x is your version number :)

Alternatively you can echo out the WP_VERSION constant in your script, it's up to you. The former is a lot quicker and easier.

Comment: Maybe true back in 2009, but as of today, no.

Comment: There is no WP_VERSION constant in newer versions of WordPress. Use the global `$wp_version` or `get_bloginfo('version')` (which will actually echo the global $wp_version...)

Answer (score 7):

From Dashboard `At a Glance` box

or at the bottom right corner of any admin page.

[image]

If that Glance box is hidden - click on `screen options` at top-right corner and check `At a Glance` option.

Answer (score 6):

Because I can not comment to @Michelle 's answer, I post my trick here.

Instead of checking the version on meta tag that usually is removed by a customized theme.

Check the `rss feed` by append `/feed` to almost any link from that site, then search for some keywords (`wordpress`, `generator`), you will have a better chance.

```
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 29 May 2015 10:08:40 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
<generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=4.2.2</generator>
```

Comment: This was the only alternative that worked in my case

Answer (score 4):

Just go to follow link
 domain.com/wp-admin/about.php

Answer (score 3):

Open the blog, Check source once the blog is open. It should have a meta tag like:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.8.4" />
```

Comment: i dont see this in my page source

Comment: Both are the same answer, yours appears to be a bit after, some people may believe you just copied it. (while I'm sure you just was a bit slower to answer ;)). I gave you a +1 for the good answer too though :)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to find the WordPress version is using [WP-CLI: Command line interface for WordPress](http://wp-cli.org/):

```
wp core version
```

Answer (score 2):

From experience with WordPress 3.8.3:

(1) Login as admin
(2) Click on the W menu in the upper left corner
(3) Click on menu item "About WordPress".

This will take you to .../wp-admin/about.php

There it will say "Welcome to WordPress 3.8.3"

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm super late regarding this topic but there's this easy to use library where you can easily get the version numbers of Worpress, PHP, Apache, and MySQL, all-in-one.

It is called the [Wordpress Environment](https://github.com/abelcallejo/wordpress-environment) (W18T) library

```
<?php
include_once 'W18T.class.php';
$environment = new W18T();
echo $environment;
?>
```

**Output**

```
{
    "platform": {
        "name": "WordPress",
        "version": "4.9.1"
    },
    "interpreter": {
        "name": "PHP",
        "version": "7.2.0"
    },
    "web_server": {
        "name": "Apache",
        "version": "2.4.16"
    },
    "database_server": {
        "name": "MySQL",
        "version": "5.7.20"
    },
    "operating_system": {
        "name": "Darwin",
        "version": "17.0.0"
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard you can see running word press version at "At a Glance"