# How to find wordpress version of a site without logging into the admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, version

I want to know version of wordpress installation without getting into the wp-admin. Just outside of the admin panel. I just want to know what version of my friend's blog currently running.
Is that possible?

Comment: Some of the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1390255/1983389 are relevant

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course, possible.

In the login form, open the page HTML source by right click > View Source or through the developer tool of your favorite browser. Then pay attention to reource version:

[image]

Taken from [here](http://tech-lives.com/find-wordpress-version-of-a-site/).