# wp-admin redirecting to wp-login

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, wp-admin

When I try to login to my wordpress admin panel, it again redirects me to the wp-login page with blank page having just "-" in the page. If I open my wp-login page manually then also I get redirect to blank page named wp-login. I have tried many possible solutions like :

- enabling wp_debug errors
- deleting .htaccess file
- etc.

When I enter username and password in wp-admin page it tells me that connection not secure. can it be the problem ? If yes, show me please how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your websites with a malware scanner tool 1st. A good start would be to use Sucuri's free online scanner (https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/). 2nd, since you have cPanel access you can login to cPanel, go to phpMyAdmin and the check your database. Access wp_options table and check these 2 entries: **siteurl** and **home**. If there you have https:// then you need to have a valid SSL certificate to get rid of that SSL warning (an expired SSL or a self signed SSL will give you that warning). You could try setting http:// instead of https:// on those 2 fields and try again to login to your Wordpress using http://siteurl/wp-login.php + login credentials. See if you get redirected or not. You should also check your .htaccess file to see if you have any redirections there from regular http connection to a secured connection. Also check if you have any plugins that do any types of redirections and you could temporary change their names via FTP or File Manager in cPanel (wordpress will disabled them).

Comment: Thanks Bogdan for reply, I have checked all above solutions that you mentioned above, though results are negative. I also upgraded wp files by downloding it from wordpress site . I read 50+ articles and applied solution to that but it failed.. It's really itching me.. How can I be helped.?

Comment: Without being able to see what exactly it's going on, checking the server logs and trying that by myself it's really hard to say or help...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem and tried the following to fix it:

1. If you're running site under `apache`, verify the `.htaccess` doesn't have anything that is redirecting user, check here [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)
2. [Disable plugins via database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624551/wordpress-deactivate-a-plugin-via-database)
3. [Make a note of the installed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390255/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-wordpress-is-running), [download the version from wordpress](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/) and replace the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders. Make sure to back up these folders up before replacing them. My method is to upload the new folders but with a different name (e.g. `wp-admin2`), then rename the original (e.g. `wp-admin1`) then rename the recently uploaded folder to `wp-admin`.

Replacing the `wp-includes` folder solved the issue for me.